# Apache Camel Circuit Breaker initially in open state

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, circuit-breaker

I wanted to try out the Apache Camel Circuit Breaker (http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) Pattern. It does not behave as I would like.

### Camel Routing

My routing looks like this

```
from("direct:foo")
        .loadBalance()
        .circuitBreaker(1, 5000, HustException.class).to("direct:pleaseHoldTheLine")
        .to("direct:bar");

from("direct:bar")
        .process(exchange -> {
            Integer value = exchange.getIn().getBody(Integer.class);
            System.out.println("[BAR] " + value);
            if (value.equals(12)) {
                throw new HustException();
            }
        });

from("direct:pleaseHoldTheLine")
        .process(exchange -> {
            Integer value = exchange.getIn().getBody(Integer.class);
            System.out.println("[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] " + value);
        });
```

### The Main Application

The main application fires Messages with Integer values from 0 to 99 each second  to the foo route.

### What I expect:

On coming to the Message with 12 the foo route throws an exeption and the pleaseHoldTheLine route should step in. After 5 seconds the foo route gets asked again and if no exception happens the foo route will take care again.

### What happens:

```
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 0
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 1
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 2
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 3
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 4
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 5
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 6
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 7
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 8
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 9
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 10
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 11
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 12
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 13
[PLEASE_HOLD_THE_LINE] 14
...
```

BW Hubert

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Camel `circuitBreaker` load balancer does not redirect the flow, it only passes or rejects messages.  The route that you have in your question will always send messages to the `"direct:pleaseHoldTheLine"` route.

If you remove the `.to("direct:pleaseHoldTheLine")` from the `"direct:foo"` route, then the circuit breaker should operate as expected and reject messages after Message 12 is received.

To stop the `DefaultErrorHandler` processing the message, you should either disable all error handling for the route using `errorHandler(noErrorHandler())` or you can specify particular exceptions that you want to skip using the global `onException(HustException.class).continued(true);` statement.

You can use the `failover` load balancer to redirect the flow, but it's not clear to me if you can combine `failover` and `circuitBreaker` to get the behaviour that you want.

Putting this all together:

```
onException(HustException.class).continued(true);
from("direct:foo")
        .loadBalance()
        .circuitBreaker(1, 5000, HustException.class)
        .to("direct:bar");
```

Comment: Hi Richard 

Thank you for your answer. I gave it a try, but it did not work either. On the first HustException _DefaultErrorHandler_ steps in and the CamelContext gets stopped.

My route looks like this:

    from("direct:foo")
            .loadBalance().circuitBreaker(1, 5000, HustException.class)
            .to("direct:bar");

My intention is to bypass the _bar_ route for a few seconds on the first HustException happening.